# Popup window slides up Animation

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I am creating an application with PopupWindow. The dialog is working fine. Now I want one animation for that window. When the dialog opens I want to slide up and down animation. I mean the screen needs to open from 50% of the screen to -2% of the screen and needs to go to 0% (I mean `android:toYDelta`). So I think it basically goes upwards and move slightly down. My issue when I use only the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="-2%p" />

</set>
```

Then screen slide up is fine and automatically moving down to its 0% position. So it makes little jerk. How can I handle this.